# Extract text between two span() iterators in python

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I am trying to extract text between two iterators.
I have tried using span() function on it to find the start and the end span 
How do I proceed further, to extract text between these spans

```
 start_matches = start_pattern.finditer(filter_lines)
 end_matches = end_pattern.finditer(filter_lines)

    for s_match in start_matches :
        s_cargo=s_match.span() 

    for e_match in end_matches :
        e_cargo=e_match.span()
```

Using the span: 1) s_cargo and 2) e_cargo, I would want to find the text within the string filter_lines

I am relatively new to python, any kind of help is much appreciated.

Comment: post a testable `filter_lines` content and expected result

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
my_data = []
for s, e in zip(s_cargo, e_cargo):
    start, _ = s
    _, end = e
    my_data.append(your_text[start: end])
```

variable `your_text` should be the text over whom you are filtering using regex